# What does this xmlns attribute do

Tags: xaml, xml-namespaces

```
<Window x:Class="Template.MainWindow"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

What does xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib means?

My ideas:
Include System from mscorlib? What about clr-namespace? So I can
use all functionality in mscorlib in Template.MainWindow.xaml.

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the namespace associated to Window tag

namespaces are used to avoid collisions when two different systems use the same tag name.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Microsoft Documentation about this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx

See the two topics:

1. The WPF and XAML Namespace Declarations
2. Mapping to Custom Classes and Assemblies

You will get idea little clear.